Pandas data frame read_CSV: why automatically make first column data as index
I'm looking at sensor data with Pandas dataframes. The text file I have does not have an index field.

It starts with time data, but when I use this code to load data from a file into a Pandas data frame,
dfSensordata = pd.read_csv(fileFolder + filename + ext, header=1, sep=',', index_col=False)
the first column, which was time data, changes to index data.

In brief, I expeced dfSensordata to be like this:



Time
1A [V]




time1
data 1


time2
data 1



but result was like this:



Index
Time
1A [V]




time1
data 1



time2
data 1




I also tried these codes, but they didn't change anything.
pd.read_csv(column_index =0)
pd.read_csv(column_index =None)
pd.read_csv(column_index =False)

Could you help me figure out what to do?

Add a sample of the csv as text, not a screenshot of it

Your problem maybe is on the first comma displayed on the csv (87,). Try to delete it from the file and reading it setting index=False. YOur are using comma as a separator for the file and it might be confussed about the first comma.

@Bokyung Seo Was the issue solved? I would appreciate you to accept and upvote the answer
